# Getting simpleName from nullable object

Tags: android, kotlin

I am just wanna print the `pendingOperation` type on the Log. But `pendingOperation` can be null.
So that i cannot write the like below:

```
private var pendingOperation: BleOperationType? = null
val operationName = pendingOperation::class.simpleName ?: "unknown operation"
```

I want to write that statement in the single line. How can do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
val nullableObj: Any? = ...
val simpleName = nullableObj?.let { it::class.simpleName }
```

Here, let is a scoping function that allows you to execute a block of code on a non-null value. If nullableObj is not null, the code inside the let block is executed and it refers to the non-null value. In the block, it::class.simpleName gets the simple name of the class of the non-null value using the :: operator.